# Can I install Nagios on Debian and can I do it from repository?

Tags: debian, software-installation, nagios

I want to install Nagios and I have my Debian VM running. On Nagios official site they say we need a minimal version of either CentOS or red hat. But can I install Nagios on Debian?
Another issue is if I can install it the easiest way, using depository? Because when I put apt-get install nagios I immediately get this E: Unable to locate package nagios

What is the very best way to install Nagios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-nagios-4-3-on-debian-9/ outlines the process.

```
apt install wget unzip zip bash-completion net-tools
```

Set the name of the host

```
hostnamectl set-hostname nagios.server.lan
```

Confirm PC hostname and hosts file

```
hostnamectl 
cat /etc/hostname
cat /etc/hosts
```

Reboot so changes may take effect

Install web server package with Nagios in it and  confirm up and running on port 80

```
apt install apache2 libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0 && netstat –tlpn
```

More detail follows in the aforementioned link.